# virtualenv LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, virtualenv

i want to start django project in virtualenv but when i try to create virtualenv in directory terminal show an error:

```
~$ cd trydjango18
:~/trydjango18$ virtualenv .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 7, in <module>
    from virtualenv import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2013, in <module>
    """)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1867, in convert
    b = base64.b64decode(s.encode('ascii'))
LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding
```

Comment: I've deleted your image since your code block shows everything of importance from it.. is `virtualenv` up to date?

Comment: Yes, virtualenv up to date. Before i try to solve it by sudo apt-get remove virtualenv. And then install newest version

Comment: similar project working on other computer with Ubuntu 15.10, and yesterday this project  works to this computer, os also Ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have solve problem

1. I copy and paste 'encodings' folder from another computer (it was in usr/lib/python2.7/encodings)
2. I install pip by this command - 
   sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential;

But when i tried to run sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper;

terminal show another error: ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler

3. After some research i understand that ssl was probably missed and i need to run

sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

sudo apt-get --reinstall install libpython2.7-stdlib

4. Then i repeat
   sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
5. all was allright, and finally 
   sudo pip install --upgrade pip

Now virtualenv doing good!